# Laravel question, How to use _GET on Blade

Tags: php, get, laravel-5.7

I have a question that I cant solve at this moment.

I have and URL like this: https://www.example.com/schedule/2020-02-26

i put the date on the URL with the next function:

```
   public function newdate($datevar)
    {       
        $Dates = Dates::all();
        return view('schedule', compact('Dates'), ['Dates' => 
     $Dates]);
    } //
```

In this example $datevar is equal to "2020-02-26"

My question is, How can I show the $datevar in my blade? Im trying with {{$datevar}} but I get an error.

To put the datevar on my function I use and other function as Request:

```
public function addnewdate(Request $request){
   $datevar = $request->input('newdate');

    return redirect()->to('schedule/'.$datevar);
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: you have to pass the variable to the blade file when you call view function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to register the URL format in the `web.php` file. In that file, add this line:

```
Route::get('/schedule/{date}', [ControllerName::class, 'addnewdate']);
```

Now, whenever the the controller method is called, it'll pass the date as an argument to your `addnewdate` method, which you need to restructure like this:

```
public function addnewdate($date){
    //Do sth with the date
}
```

Comment: Yes, I do it this and working, but How can I show the date on my blade.php?

Comment: You already did with `view('schedule', compact('Dates'), ['Dates' => 
     $Dates]);` Just access the `$Dates` variable from your blade file.

Comment: No, I dont need the $Dates on my blade.php I need to see the $datevar on my blade.php

Comment: Alright, so add that in. `return view('schedule')->with('Dates', $Dates)->with('dateVar', $datevar)`.

Comment: I appreacite your help, is Working now :D